# Syntax to POST query to Soil Data Access Web Service

Tags: post

I want to query the SSURGO data through the "post.rest" service described here:

http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx#PostRest

The way I'm reading the documentation, I think this should return a result:

```
curl -d "SELECT * from component where mukey = '458913' ORDER BY comppct_r DESC" http://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService/post.rest
```

However, I get the error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException>
Cannot parse ampersand-delimited POST request</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The error doesn't make sense because my query doesn't have an ampersand.

I have confirmed that the query `SELECT * from component where mukey = '458913' ORDER BY comppct_r DESC` is valid by running it here:

http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Query.aspx

I tried a variety of different header and body variations, but nothing helped.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to format the params as json. For example, this works:

```
echo "{query: \"SELECT * from component where mukey = '458913' ORDER BY comppct_r DESC\"}" > query.sql
curl -d @query.sql http://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Tabular/post.rest
```

I was able to reverse engineer this from this R library:

https://github.com/cran/soilDB/blob/8899bb054b3efdfbbbff898ba31d7763aba68506/R/SDA_query.R#L129-L133

Answer (score 0):

You are not using POST in your curl command. It needs `-X POST`.  And you need to set the content header to text/sql or something so it isn't form encoded.

Comment: The command `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/sql" -d "SELECT * from component where mukey = '458913' ORDER BY comppct_r DESC" http://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Tabular/SDMTabularService/post.rest` explicitly does a POST and sets the content header to text/sql. Same error.

Comment: Do the docs say what format they expect?

Comment: The first link in the question links directly to the relevant docs. As you can see, it is ambiguously defined as `{ Query }`. I figured out the answer below.